# How to vertical centre align my text in a table in onenote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2013

How could I vertically centre align text in a table in OneNote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot vertically center text in a table in OneNote

I too had this issue. Try as a might, I could not find a way to do it.
The only solution seems to be to use the "Insert a Microsoft Excel Spreadsheet"
Within Excel you can format the table to your liking, hit the save button and the changes will replicate to the embedded spreadsheet in OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the whole table
- Cut, and paste into a Word document
- Do the necessary alignment changes
- Select the whole table
- Cut, and paste back into OneNote.

Comment: This keeps the vertical alignment ONLY if you paste as a (mostly-useless) picture...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could do this is by having equal spacing above and below the text using paragraph OR if I want it at the bottom I enter a space and then the enter key until the text is at the bottom of the box.   I do wish they would make one note a little more robust

Answer (score 0):

In the table cell you want something centered vertically in, insert a single cell (a cell inside a cell). Then enter your text or object in that new cell and hide the border of it.  You may need to add empty lines or whatnot to get it exactly where you want it, depending on what you are working with.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Align text in a table in different ways to make the table easier to read and understand. Typically, numbers are right-aligned so that they line up under one another and can be compared more easily. Labels are typically center-aligned or left-aligned. OneNote provides Alignment buttons on the Table Tools Layout tab for aligning text.

1. Click anywhere in the table.
2. Click the Layout tab.
3. Select the rows, columns, or cells with the data you want to
   realign; or select the entire table.
4. Click an Alignment button (Align Left, Center, or Align Right).

Comment: I am asking about how to "Vertically" align, not horizontally align.

Answer (score -1):

No way that I am aware of to VERTICALLY align in OneNote, or most other programs, for that matter.  Insert an Excel table, where it is possible.

Comment: Actually... It is possible in most of the Office apps- Word, Excell, PPoint...

Answer (score -1):

For me, if I just have some table cells selected, the align paragraph button can be used to center the text but if I select the whole table, OneNote centers the whole table on the page as well as the text in the cells.  To just center the text, I centered the top row and then centered the rest of the rows separately.

Comment: The question is about *vertically* centering text.  Your post appears to be about *horizontally* centering text, and so is not responsive to the question.   If you actually are talking about *vertical* centering, please [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -2):

At the top, click the 'toolbar options' arrow (next to ZOOM, shows as '100%')

Click the 'Add or Remove Buttons' option and select 'Formatting'

A list of options appears. Place a check/tick next to the options you want featured at the top. In this case select 'Align Left', 'Centre' or 'Align Right'

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not answer the question "how to **vertical** centre align" - this is for horizontal alignment only.